# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'width' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

Not much of a javascript person, so you'll have to forgive me. I'm trying to get this HTML template in shape but I keep running into an error that I believe is causing some layout issues.

Here's the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'width' of nulL at e
>   (animated1.self-b9a4c7f67d0005da19c8ed8c98254dd633747e3b9330fd1ca028e36c397fd765.js:6)
>   at
>   animated1.self-b9a4c7f67d0005da19c8ed8c98254dd633747e3b9330fd1ca028e36c397fd765.js:94
>   at
>   animated1.self-b9a4c7f67d0005da19c8ed8c98254dd633747e3b9330fd1ca028e36c397fd765.js:95

Here's the snippet of code from animated1

```
! function() {
function e() {
    u = window.innerWidth, v = window.innerHeight, g = {
        x: u / 2,
        y: v / 2
    }, f = document.getElementById("main-header"), h = document.getElementById("demo-canvas"), h.width = u, h.height = v, m = h.getContext("2d"), w = [];
    for (var e = 0; u > e; e += u / 20)
        for (var n = 0; v > n; n += v / 20) {
            var t = e + Math.random() * u / 20,
                o = n + Math.random() * v / 20,
                i = {
                    x: t,
                    originX: t,
                    y: o,
                    originY: o
                };
            w.push(i)
        }
    for (var a = 0; a < w.length; a++) {
        for (var r = [], c = w[a], l = 0; l < w.length; l++) {
            var y = w[l];
            if (c != y) {
                for (var p = !1, M = 0; 5 > M; M++) p || void 0 == r[M] && (r[M] = y, p = !0);
                for (var M = 0; 5 > M; M++) p || s(c, y) < s(c, r[M]) && (r[M] = y, p = !0)
            }
        }
        c.closest = r
    }
    for (var a in w) {
        var b = new d(w[a], 2 + 2 * Math.random(), "rgba(255,255,255,0.3)");
        w[a].circle = b
    }
}
```

This is the HTML section

```
<header id="main-header" class="parallax-main-header" data-scroll-index="0">
<canvas class="hide-on-med-and-down" id="demo-canvas"></canvas>
<div class="overlay gradient-color"></div>

<div id="scene" data-hover-only="true" data-relative-input="true" class="parallax" >

    <div class="layer" data-depth="1.0">
```

I believe the issue is with

> h.width= u

on line 6 and since that seems to get its value from

> window.innerWidth

which should return a value in pixels, but for some reason, it doesn't seem to be getting that - hence the null return -. I'm using Rails 5 as well and the rest of my javascript is loaded (and called out at the bottom of the page) just fine so I'm not sure what's happening here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error means that `h` is `null`, not that the width value is null.

Comment: The problem is not the `u`. The problem is the `h`. Read the error message carefully. It's there to instruct you.

Comment: Also, you're debugging minified code. That never helps.

Comment: You have `h = document.getElementById("demo-canvas"), h.width = u`; h is not an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`h = document.getElementById("demo-canvas"), h.width = u;` h is not an object

Your h object is null.
Your `h` value is not an object to have `width` property. Maybe you can consider initializing `var h = {}` and then after you can use it `h.width=u`.

[getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) return an element or null is there is no element with the given id. So you need to check first if `document.getElementById("demo-canvas")` is not null or not.

```
var h = document.getElementById("demo-canvas")
if(h){
  h.width=u; 
  // you can put here all the others assignments related to h
}
```

Comment: Which means that the OP needs to check whether there is an element with `id = "demo-canvas"`, correct? Because that (presumably failed) assignment (`h = document.getElementById("demo-canvas")`) is the precursor to the reported error?

Comment: Forgot to add the html in my original post, updated.

Comment: @niharvey, if you made the changes I suggested, you will no longer have the same error

Comment: I hate to ask such a silly request, but I can't seem to add it in correctly (again <0 knowledge of javascript :) ) Everytime I plug it in where I think it should go, I get an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var"

Comment: remove the `var` keyword

Comment: grrr.... down the rabbit hole I go. new Error : Uncaught TypeError: h.getContext is not a function

Comment: @jvillian Just checking if an element with `id = "demo-canvas"`exists may work, isn't - strictly speaking - "correct", though. A run-time error could still prevent `h` actually pointing to that element. I would recommend actually checking that assigning h the element actually worked!

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek - That is a GREAT comment! You are 100% correct. I suppose what I meant was that the OP should visually examine the DOM to ensure the "demo-canvas" element existed. But, you are dead on. Ultimately, in code, if you wanted to have a safety check, you would check the result of the assignment, not the presence of the element. Good one! Thanks!

Comment: @jvillian, I edited the answer based on your comment. I don't know if that is what you meant

Comment: @niharvey, it the question helped you do not forget to accept and upvote it :)

Answer (score 0):

The script tag in your HTML code is probably in the wrong place. If the script tag is at the head tag of your HTML code, then you will get this message because the JavaScript is looking for an element that isn't there yet. HTML reads from top to bottom, so if your JavaScript is looking for an element that isn't there before the script tag, then the code will say the value is null, and you will get this error most times. Put your script tag just before the closing body tag in your HTML code block, and your JavaScript code will probably work just fine. For instance:

```
    <body>
        "stuff & stuff & more stuff"
        <script src = "yourSourceFileHereIf_Its_A_SeparateFile.js"></ script>
    </body>
```